# Erro ao usar random

Tags: c#, random

Defini um numero randomico para preencher uma tabela ficticia e fiz assim:

```
    foreach (var usuario in LstUsuarios)
    {
        htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<tr>");
        htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td>" + usuario.Nome + "</td>");
        htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td><strong>" + usuario.NomePerfil + "</strong></td>");
        htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td>" + usuario.UnidadeGerencial.Txt_Sigla_UG + "</td>");

        for (var i = 1; i <= num_periodos; i++)
        {
            rnd = new Random();
            random = rnd.Next(1, 99);
            htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td> " + random + "</td>");
        }
        htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td>100</td>");
        htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("</tr>");
    }
```

Porém na aplicação está aparecendo sempre o mesmo número.

O curioso é que quando eu debugo no visual studio ele realmente gera números diferentes.

O que está fora da linha vermelha é a parte que eu debuguei no VS, fui verificando com os breakpoints e os numeros iam mudando. Mas quando eu apertava continue no VS ele voltava a gerar o mesmo número que são os que estão dentro da linha vermelha.

Não entendi o por quê disso. Alguma idéia?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coloque a `instância` do [`Random()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) fora do `for` no seu caso:

```
rnd = new Random();
foreach (var usuario in LstUsuarios)
{
    htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<tr>");
    htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td>" + usuario.Nome + "</td>");
    htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td><strong>" + usuario.NomePerfil + "</strong></td>");
    htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td>" + usuario.UnidadeGerencial.Txt_Sigla_UG + "</td>");

    for (var i = 1; i <= num_periodos; i++)
    {            
        random = rnd.Next(1, 99);
        htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td> " + random + "</td>");
    }
    htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("<td>100</td>");
    htmlUsuarios.AppendLine("</tr>");
}
```

**Porque?**

Como está sendo criado o [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) dentro do for cada item gerado é uma nova instância, e com isso o Seed inicial é o mesmo, fato calculado pelo [Enviroment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.environment.tickcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Sobre o debug:**

Justamente por causa do [Enviroment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.environment.tickcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) vai ter outro valor no `debug`, e em cada <kbd>F11</kbd> por exemplo, vai mudar o cálculo do milissegundos.

Comment: Só acrescentaria um detalhe a dizer que isto acontece porque como uma instância do `Random` é criada a cada iteração, a `seed` vai ser a mesma (sem passar uma `seed` o `Random` usa o `Enviroment.TickCount`) e daí ter números repetidos. O comportamento não era observado durante `Debug` porque o código vai ser executado mais lentamente o que permite ter `seeds` diferentes.

Comment: @Omni isso mesmo !!!

Comment: E vocês tem ideia de porque quando estou debugando ele gera numeros diferentes?

Comment: Justamento por causa do  Enviroment.TickCount vai ter outro valor no debug, e em cada F11 por, exemplo, ele vai mudar o calculo do milissegundos

Comment: @JoaoPaulo "O comportamento não era observado durante Debug porque o código vai ser executado mais lentamente o que permite ter seeds diferentes." Esta lentidão pode vir do utilizador estar a fazer debug passo a passo ou do simples overhead causado pelo debugger.